# How to disable RTL support in Android Studio (editing source code)?

Tags: android, android-studio, bidi

**Issue:** my project supports 68 languages, several of which are RTL languages (Farsi, Arabic, Hebrew, etc.). We use Crowdin for translation of our base English text. Sometimes when I import the latest translations, my `strings.xml` file contains improperly formatted string resources. For example, a string formatting arg like `%s` might be inverted (`s%`) or even just plain wrong (a dangling `%`). This can lead to runtime crashes.

I would like to be able to easily edit my `strings.xml` file, but the default behavior of Android Studio is to render RTL text from right-to-left. This makes it impossible to edit directly in the IDE with a LTR keyboard layout.

**How do I disable RTL "support" in Android Studio so I can easily edit text files with mixed RTL and LTR text?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a brief discussion with the JetBrains team, I found the answer [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177196). With Linux, you can hit the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and click on the **Registry** option. Search for **editor.disable.rtl** and check the box to disable RTL support. Restart Android Studio. Done!